# NVIDIA Optimus GEFORCE GT 540M not recognised as a proprietary driver

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, graphics

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, when I first install Ubuntu 11.10 as a dual boot on my Acer Aspire 5750G laptop, I could select my additional driver, my Nvidia graphics card and I got informed to reboot. I did this and now I get presented with the following:

[image]

I've been looking around for a good day trying to find a solution, I'm new to Ubuntu. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling, purging, and reinstalling jockey?

Comment: how do I go about doing that? I understand how to use the terminal, just haven't learnt all the codes.

Comment: dpkg --get-selections | grep jockey.  apt-get remove --purge packagename(probably jockey and jockey-gtk).  reboot.  apt-get install jockey-gtk.  the reboot is probably unnecessary...but i'm weird that way on desktop installs.\

Comment: no luck, uninstalled, purged, restarted and reinstalled but the list still shows up empty..

Comment: sorry, I forgot to thank you for your help, great to get responses from people, shame it hasn't come to fix my problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by myself with a lot of trial and error and finding a useful program called Ironhide, a project continued from Bumblebee.

Install instructions can be found here:

http://hybrid-graphics-linux.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Ironhide

I did as they said, configured it twice, restarted and everything works like a charm.

Hopefully this will help others otu there if you have the same problem as I did.